# Grid view Data on user control using C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When i try to get data grid using user control I have got an an error like this
could not load file or assembly 'mysql.data, version=6.1.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: It seems the usercontrol is binding the datasource to a mysql database try this https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/

Comment: You need to show the code you are using. Otherwise we can just quess what the problem is. Where in your code is this exception coming from ?